# List of visible windows in C# returning invisible windows

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

i was trying to get a list of all visible windows using c# and the windows API but for some reason my code returns this even with no windows open.

```
Title:Microsoft Text Input Application Bounds:{X:0 Y:0 Width:1920 Height:1080} Layer:4
Title:Program Manager Bounds:{X:0 Y:0 Width:1920 Height:1080} Layer:5
```

I wanted to get only the apps trully visible but i had no luck solving this problem.
Here is my code so far:

```
public static List<Window> GetWindows()
{
    List<Window> AllWindows = new List<Window>();
    IntPtr WindowHandle = GetTopWindow(DesktophWnd);

    int LayerIndex = 1;

    while (WindowHandle != new IntPtr(0))
    {

        StringBuilder Buffer = new StringBuilder(BufferSize);
        GetWindowTextA(WindowHandle, Buffer, BufferSize);

        Rect R = new Rect();
        GetWindowRect(WindowHandle, ref R);

        if (IsWindowVisible(WindowHandle) && Buffer.Length > 0 && WindowHandle != hWnd && !IsIconic(WindowHandle))
        {
            var Rect = new Rectangle(R.Left, R.Top, R.Right - R.Left, R.Bottom - R.Top);
            Window W = new Window(WindowHandle, Buffer.ToString(), Rect, LayerIndex, R);
            AllWindows.Add(W);
            LayerIndex++;

            //Debug
            Console.WriteLine($"Title:{W.Title} Bounds:{W.Bounds} Layer:{W.Layer}");

        }

        WindowHandle = GetWindow(WindowHandle, GW_HWNDNEXT);

    }
    return AllWindows;
}
```

Comment: On a side note, you should not be using `GetWindow()` in a loop like this. Use `EnumWindows()` with a callback instead.

Comment: How is `IsWindowVisible` defined? Your concept of "visible windows" does not match what the function is testing.

Comment: I think [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200302-00/?p=103507) might help you.

Comment: yes it was exacly what i wanted but somehow program manager still appears even after i check for ItsCloaked